# I need to calculate the average production per employee per month

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I need to create a report showing the employees that produced on average at least 30 pieces/ day

I have 2 tables:

```
Employees: id, name, surname
Production: id, date_time, id_employee, [..], quantity_produced
```

the id from the employees table = id_employee from the production table

---

```
SELECT name, surname, Avg(quantity_produced), Month(data_ora) Mnth
FROM production inner join employees on employees.id = production.id_employee
GROUP BY name, quantity_produced, Month(date_time);
```

OR

```
select name, surname, quantity_produced, avg(quantity_produced) as avgentrypermonth 
    from (
select month(date_time) as month ,count(1) as quantity
     group by month(date_time));
```

OR

```
select name, surname, quantity_produced
    from production 
     inner join employees on employees.id = production.id_employee
    where avg(quantity_produced) > 30;
```

Comment: do you need to AVG all months in all years????

Comment: What's the problem with the given queries? Can you share what works yet, and where you need help?

Answer (score 1):

I would most likely go for one off the queries below.

But hard to suggest something solid without example data and expected results.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    Production.id_employee,
    AVG(Production.quantity_produced)
FROM 
    Production
WHERE
    Production.date_time BETWEEN
                         (LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH # first day of current month
                         AND
                         LAST_DAY(NOW()) # last day of current month
GROUP BY 
    Production.id_employee
```

Query when you need the employees record instead:

```
SELECT 
    Employees.name,
    Employees.surname,
    AVG(Production.quantity_produced)
FROM 
    Production
INNER JOIN 
    Employees ON Production.id_employee = Employees.id
WHERE
    Production.date_time BETWEEN
                         (LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH  # first day of current month
                         AND
                         LAST_DAY(NOW()) # last day of current month
GROUP BY 
    Employees.id
```

Note the query above assumes at least MySQL 5.7.5+ and SQL 1999+ standards optional feature which is called [functional dependency](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html).

See [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Or as co-related subqueries: which should be fine when indexed correctly

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT Employees.name FROM Employees.id = Production.id_employee) AS name,
    (SELECT Employees.surname FROM Employees.id = Production.id_employee) AS surname,
    AVG(Production.quantity_produced)
FROM 
    Production
WHERE
    Production.date_time BETWEEN
                         (LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH # first day of current month
                         AND LAST_DAY(NOW()) # last day of current month
GROUP BY 
    Production.id_employee
```

Answer (score 0):

for filter aggregated  result you need  having clause

```
SELECT name, surname, Avg(quantity_produced), Month(date_time) Mnth
FROM production 
inner join employees on employees.id = production.id_employee
GROUP BY name, surname, Month(date_time)
having Avg(quantity_produced) > 30 ;
```

and with year  too

```
SELECT name, surname, Avg(quantity_produced), Month(date_time) Mnth, year(date_time) year
FROM production 
inner join employees on employees.id = production.id_employee
GROUP BY name, surname, Month(date_time), year(date_time) year
having Avg(quantity_produced) > 30 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with months, you should be sure that you are taking the year into account as well:

```
SELECT year(p.data_ora) as yyyy, month(p.data_ora) as mm,
       e.name, e.surname, avg(p.quantity_produced),
FROM production p inner join
     employees e
     on e.id = p.id_employee
GROUP BY year(p.data_ora), month(p.data_ora,
         e.name, e.surname
HAVING avg(p.quantity_produced) >= 30
ORDER BY year(p.data_ora), month(p.data_ora),
         e.name, e.surname;
```

This assumes that `production` has the quantity produced per day that the employee works.

Notes:

- Qualify all column references when your table references more than one table.
- Use table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.
- Remember the year! (when you are working with months)

Answer (score 0):

```
    I think this should work , can you please try it once. And may be little modification required, Comment here I will try to do the fixes.
  1.Select
         E.id "Employee ID",
         E.name "Employee Name",
         Month(P.date_time) "Month",
         AVG(P.quantity_produced) "Quantity Produced"
    From Employee as E
         Join Production as P on E.id=P. id_employee
    Group by
         E.id,E.name,Month(P.date_time)
    Having Avg(P.quantity_produced) > 30

2.Select
         E.name "Employee Name",
         Month(P.date_time) "Month",
         AVG(P.quantity_produced) "Quantity Produced"
    From Employee as E
         Join Production as P on E.id=P. id_employee
    Group by
         E.name,Month(P.date_time)
    Having Avg(P.quantity_produced) > 30
```

Comment: fair warning: this query above assumes atleast MySQL 5.7.5+ and SQL 1999+ standards optional feature which is called [functional dependency](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html)... see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: I wrote it based on MS SQL Server standards.

Comment: Then your SQL should fail as SQL Server does not support these kind off queries as E.name is not in the GROUP BY.. SQL Server does not support functional dependency

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out. You are correct. I will add it to the group by part.

Comment: And as per my understanding, If we will take ID only in both the places (group by and select) then it will perform better. Because most of the time id is a primary key(or you can say clustered index) and it will make it faster. Putting name will make it little slow. What do you think.

Comment: One more thing. I saw your answer , can you tell me if it is optimised. I found them little come complex. I want to become boss of SQL so just asking to learn more.

Comment: We are going offtopic here.. But complex SQL does not directly relate to performance as the Optimizer is a heavy beast to understand... in general to give a small example.. The MySQL optimizer can't use a index when a `GROUP BY` clause uses columns which are from two or more separted tables as `Group by E.name,Month(P.date_time)` does and would require a temp table/CPU sort to be processed. Well in SQL Server you could/should optimize this with a indexed view. So yes mine approach in MySQL should have better performance assuming the correct indexes are used for the complete queries.